# Problem with a proof of theorem about diagonalization for selfadjoint operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $F: X \rightarrow X$ is a self-adjoint operator on a $n$-dimensional unitary vector space $X$ with $Spec T=\{a_1,..., a_r\}$.  Let $E_i$, for $i=1,...,r$, be orthogonal projections on eigenvectorspaces of $F$
and let $E=E_1+...+E_r$.

I know that then $E_1+...+E_r$ is orthogonal projection, because the images of $E_i$ and $E_j$ for $i\neq j$ are orthogonal.

I try to prove that $E$ is the identity operator using the following ideas:

> If $E\neq Id$  then $F$ has $V:=Im (I-E)$ as nonzero invariant subspace and $F|_V$ has no eigenvalues? 
>   How to prove this statement?

Comment: I suppose that the dimension of $Im(E_i)$ equals the multiplicity of $a_i$, so the dimsneion of $Im(E)$ equals $n$. So $Im(E)=X$ and $E$ is an isomorphism and "orthogonal projection".

Comment: But you used the spectral theorem. I try to proved this theorem in another way, using the idea of P. Halmos, Finite dimensional vector spaces, par.79, thr.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $\mathrm{Im}(I-E)$ is an invariant subspace of $F$, note that $\mathrm{Im}(E_i)$  are $F$-invariant.

Assume $F|_V$ has an eigenvector $v$. This implies that $v$ is an eigenvector of $F$ as well. Hence $v\in \mathrm{Im}E_i$ for some $i$, which implies $v\in \mathrm{Im}(E)$. However, $v\in V=\mathrm{Im}(I-E)=\mathrm{Ker}(E)$. But $\mathrm{Ker}(E)\cap \mathrm{Im}(E)=\{0\}$. Hence $v=0$, which is a contradiction.